# git format-patch in multiple-branch setup

Tags: git, version-control, linux-kernel, format-patch

**1. Abstract**

My ultimate goal is to bring some Client's changes done on a Client's branch in the linux-kernel repo to another linux-kernel repository, given the fact that both have a common base tag (e.g. v4.2, from which the Client's branch has been initially created).

For that I am trying to create a stack of patches representing the diff between the base and the head of the Client's branch. During this first step, I am using `git format-patch`. The second step is applying those patches in the second repo using `git am`.

`git diff` and GNU `diff` are not of interest to me, as I don't want to lose the commit metadata (author, message, etc).

**2. Demo setup**

I have created a simple git commit flow to exemplify the problem. The following graphs depict the branch setup of this [demo repo](https://github.com/erosca/SO_q1.git):

1. `Gitg` graph - commit time order:
   [image]
2. `Gitg` graph - topological order: [image]
3. `Gitk` graph:
   [image]
4. `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`:
   [image]

**3. Steps to reproduce the issue**

- `$ git status`
  `On branch master
  Your branch is up-to-date with origin/master.
  nothing to commit, working directory clean.`
- `$ git format-patch BASE`
  `0001-commit-2-br1.patch`
- `$ git checkout BASE`
  `HEAD is now at 65772fd... commit 3-master`
- `$ git apply 0001-commit-2-br1.patch`
  `error: patch failed: file:1
  error: file: patch does not apply`

**4. Additional info & Questions**

- `git diff BASE f316460 > my.patch` works! However, as stated in the Abstract, this is not a solution for me.
- I believe `git format-patch` is just not smart enough in the multiple branch setup. Have anyone run into the same problems?
- Are there any methods to achieve the same goal without `git format-patch`?

Comment: You have to read documentation on `git rebase` command, in particular on `git rebase --onto`. Do not reinvent a wheel, please.

Comment: @Andy Shevchenko: Thanks, I've managed to simply rebase the new local branch to the Client's remote branch. However, the `git format-patch` problem is still valid, from my point of view.

Comment: You did apparently something difficult to understand. You have a merge commit, which is unusual to Git (yes, merge commits are exceptions and handled in a specific way). I'm pretty sure that `git format-patch` created something different to what you have in `git diff`. You may try to run `patch -p1 < 0001-commit-2-br1.patch` and see what is wrong.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: To me the commit diagram looks pretty simple and common. `git am`, `git apply` and GNU `patch` *all* fail. `git format-patch` fails even when considering as `BASE` the first commit (I would have chosen that case, if I knew it before starting this thread).

Comment: **You may try to run `patch -p1 < 0001-commit-2-br1.patch` and see WHAT WENT WRONG.**

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: I appreciate your intention to help, but non-bold fonts are fine enough to communicate your ideas to people :). If no git guru makes his appearance in this thread in the nearest future, I am going to just post the conclusions of my analysis in a separate answer.